# How to set project configuration properties through QT .PRO file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

Is there a way I can set project configuration properties for a Visual Studio project created through a QT .PRO file? More specifically I want to enable profiling under "Configuration Properties > Linker > Advanced".
[Image showing the relevant Linker setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ihvX.png)

Based on my research there seems to be certain flags that can be defined in the file like "QMAKE_CXXFLAGS" or "QMAKE_LFLAGS" but I can't seem to get it to work.

Edit: Just to clarify a bit, I have tried setting these

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -profile=true
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -profile=true
```

at the top of the .PRO file, because the setting appears to translate to 
"< Profile>true< /Profile>" in the vcxproj XML file.

Comment: Post what you tried.

Comment: I tried setting "QMAKE_LFLAGS += -profile=true" and "QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -profile=true" at the top of the file

Comment: Try writing `QMAKE_LFLAGS += /PROFILE`

Comment: You can also pass properties as arguments when you call `qmake`.

Comment: @Satus Wow it actually worked, "/PROFILE" shows up under < AdditionalOptions > and the errors I was getting went away. Thanks!!